# Continuity and norm of a functional

Tags: integration, continuity, normed-spaces

Let $E = \mathbb{R} [X]$ equipped with the norm $||p|| = \int_0^1 (|p(t)| + |p'(t)|) \ d t $.

Check if the functional $\psi : E \ni p \rightarrow p(0) \in \mathbb{R}$ is continuous, and if it is, find its norm.

$p,q \in E, \ ||p-q||= \int_0^1 (|p(t)-q(t)| + |p'(t) - q'(t)|) \ dt = $

$\int_0^1 (|p(t)-q(t)|) dt + \int_0^1 (|p'(t) - q'(t)|) \ dt = $

$\int_0^1 (|p(t)-q(t)|) dt +|p(1)-q(1)| - |p(0) + q(0)|$

And $||\psi (p) - \psi (q)|| = |p(0) - q(0)|$

Could you tell me if it is correct and what I can do next?

Thank you!

Comment: $\int |f'| \ne |f|$. You have an error in the final step of $\|p-q\|$.

Comment: I see, so I need to know when $p'(t)-q'(t) \ge 0$ and when it is $<0$. But how can I find that out?

Comment: Bring in a $\mathop{\rm sgn}(p'(t) - q'(t))$ with a derivative of $0$ a.e. and use partial integration on $|x| = \mathop{\rm sgn}(x) x$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\psi$ is linear, so we need only check that $\psi$ is bounded.

$|p(0)| = |\int_0^1 p(0) dx| = |\int_0^1 (p(0)-p(x) + p(x)) dx| \le \int_0^1 (|p(0)-p(x)| + |p(x)| ) dx$.

Note that $p(0)-p(x) = \int_0^x -p'(t) dt$ (this is the key part of this solution), hence $|p(0)-p(x)| \le \int_0^1 |p'(t)| dt$.

Then $|p(0)| \le \int_0^1 (\int_0^1 |p'(t)| dt ) + |p(x)| ) dx  = \|p\|$. Hence $\|\psi\| \le 1$.

If we let $p(x) = 1$, we have $\phi(p) = 1$ and $\|p\| = 1$, hence $\| \psi \| = 1$.

Comment: Thank you. In order to find its norm I need to find $\sup \{ |p(0)|, \int_0^1 (|p(t)| + |p'(t)|) dt =1 \}$, right?

Comment: That is one way. (I don't know what $\|\psi\|$ is.)

Comment: I uploaded my comment right after you edited your answer. Thanks again for the help!

Comment: I have a few questions. $||p|| = \int_0^1 (|p(t)| + |p'(t)|) \ d t$ and in your solution it is $\int_0^1 (\int_0^1 |p'(t)| dt ) + |p(x)| ) dx $. Why is it equal? The second question is why $p(0)-p(x) = \int_0^1 -p'(t) dt$? I'm afraid I still don't see that.

Comment: Note that $\int_0^1 ( \int_0^1 |p'(t)|dt) dx=  \int_0^1 |p'(t)|dt$, so $\int_0^1 (\int_0^1 |p'(t)| dt ) + |p(x)| ) dx = \int_0^1 |p'(t)|dt + \int_0^1 |p(x)|dx$. The variables $x,t$ are just 'dummy' integration variables. The fundamental theorem of calculus gives $p(x) = p(0)+ \int_0^x p'(t)dt$. Let $x=1$.

Comment: So if $x=1, \ p(0)-p(1) = \int _0^x p'(t) dt$, isn't that so? Why is there $p(0) - p(x)$?

Comment: I don't understand your last question.

Comment: What I mean is, in this equation $p(0)−p(x)=∫^1_0−p′(t)dt $ there is $x$ on the left and it doesn't apprear on the right, and the fundamental theorem of calculus says that in this equation the limits of the integral should be $0,x$, not $0,1$

Comment: Ok, everything is clear now.

Comment: I had a little typo. above. You have $|p(0)-p(x)| \le \int_0^x |p'(t)|dt \le \int_0^1 |p'(t)| dt$.